# Encrypting data on client app before sending it to server

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to create an app that will encrypt all user input data before sending it to server where it will be stored in sql database. The idea is that data in database is always encrypted and that it can only be decrypted back on client app so I was thinking of creating and storing private key on client app. 
Second requirement is that all apps can decrypt data written on server db, so I presume all apps should share the same private key.

My question is:

- How can I store private key in my project so that it will be secured:
  I was thinking on obfuscating it and then storing it to keychain, but
  as I understand neither obfuscation nor keychain are very safe. My
  concern is if all of my app instances use same private key than
  hacker could easily gain access to my data just by jailbreaking his
  own phone. If I generate it on the fly than all apps will have
  different private keys, and wont be able to share data in readable
  form
- What are some best practices in achieving this goal, If the keychain
  is unsafe, is there some other place or way of doing this, if there
  is not I will use keychain but at least I would like to solve problem
  of hardcoding key in project so that it can be saved in keychain on
  first run

**EDIT**

just to clarify a bit more

Lets say we have something like a cloud service, and every cloud can have many devices joined. All devices get synced with its cloud when one of them changes some resource. That cloud is represented with a profile that contains some personal data about user who owns the devices. I would like that all of the devices joined to cloud (C1) can see(read) that personal data that is associated with that cloud, what I wouldn’t like is that some db admin can read that data. So I want to encrypt data on client side, and decrypt it on client side.

In short, the encryption is not for transport purposes, for thet I use ssl, its just a try to conform to new GDPR regulative about security of personal data.

**EDIT 1**

After some investigating I have found something called "Client side encryption". It perfectly matches my needs, data is encrypted on client, it is send to server where it is stored in db, and it is decrypted on client again. But I cant seem to find a way to deal with the need to hardcode private key in my project. In order to save it to keychain I have to load it from some place, and if I generate it than the other client wont have the same key and it wont be able to decrypt data. So can anybody help me, am I looking at this from a wrong angle?

Comment: If every client can read every other client's data, what is the attack you're trying to protect against by encrypting it in your database? If the client has access to a key, then anyone who has the client will have access to that key. That is not a solvable problem.

Comment: It is not the whole implementation, there will be groups of users that can read some data and other groups that can read other data with different key, but that is not the point of my question, the point is how can I make data readable only on client apps, but not on server side database

Comment: OK; that's solvable, but if you don't trust the device (I take it you're concerned that the device is stolen?) then you will have to store some part of the secret in the user (i.e. a password or PIN that must be entered). With that, you can secure this as Don suggests below, using public/private keys. The clients will need a transport to negotiate among themselves (though the transport does not have to be secure).

Comment: For example: if Alice wants to share data she has encrypted with Bob, Alice generates a random symmetric encryption key and stores it locally. She can then encrypt that key with Bob's public key so that he can read it as well. Many key sharing schemes follow this basic pattern, and it's probably what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the use of TLS, from your question, we can outline the following requirements that you have made:

- All information stored on the server must be encrypted in such a way that a server breach will not leak any data.
- All clients in a given "cloud" can access all data in that cloud.
- Loss of a client device will leak no information from the cloud.

We can then outline a E2E scheme like so:

1. When a user is first created, generate a public/private key client-side and transmit the public key to the server.  Encrypt the private key client-side with a symmetric key generated from the users password.  Any actions that require this private key thus also require the users password, protecting from device theft.
2. When a user wishes to create a "cloud group", generate a symmetric key for this group and encrypt it with the users public key.  Store this key on the client device, encrypted with the users public key.
3. When the user wants to add another user to their "cloud group", encrypt the group symmetric key with the new users public key and transmit.
4. Communication and storage within the "cloud group" uses the group symmetric key.

Note that in this scheme:

- The server cannot decrypt any of the data because the group symmetric key only ever touches the server while encrypted by a specific users public key.
- The users password is always required to use their private key and thus theft of a device cannot expose any information to the thief.
- All users of the "cloud group" can communicate with each other using a simple symmetric algorithm.

Comment: I think we are on to something here, there is just one thing unclear to me and it concerns "cloud groups".  The resources in my example are created and encrypted by devices and stored at server side (also encrypted). If I encrypt the resource with the same key I used to encrypt cloud data, then I wont be able to share the resource with other clouds, and in order to share I will need to encrypt data with some common resource key or? The share function doesn't work between devices itself, but one device just notifies cloud to create a new reference between new cloud and that resource.

Comment: Never mind I just realised you have already answered everything, thank you very much :)

Comment: Add a feature where the client app times-out after a certain period of non-foreground use, or after N hours regardless of use---discarding the symmetric key derived from the user password---and you're about as safe from handset-theft as you can be.

Comment: Does it have to be stored? I mean if I can derive it from password every time I need it, can I just calculate it on demand, encrypt/decrypt and forget it?

Comment: @AntonijoDev, Luke Joshua Park.. considering the user as a mobile app, what happens if the user clears the app data or uninstalls the app? after reinstalling and logging again, will the regenerated public/private be the same and will he be able to access previous data as earlier?

Comment: @codin No, a different private key will be generated and they won't be able to access their data.  As a way around this, you could have your app transmit the (symmetrically encrypted) private key to the server when it is created.  This way a user could retrieve their private key using their email address but only access it with the correct password.

Answer (score 2):

You could mimic the way iMessages works: https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

At a high level: a public-private key pair is generated on the device, and the private key is stored in the keychain.  The public key is registered on a server and associated with the user/device.  When a message is sent, the service looks up the public key of the recipient and encrypts the message using that, so that only the recipient can decrypt it.

Apple uses the keychain, so take that as you will regarding the safety of it.

Comment: Yes I can see how this would be practical in some messaging app, but I don't see how could I apply it to my problem. I have edited my question to clarify what exactly I am aiming for

Answer (score 2):

Even if the private key is stolen from the client, an attacker can only decrypt the cyphertext if they have the cyphertext.

The server and client should only send each other cyphertext once they have  authenticated themselves to each other.

Then, if the sending of data happens over a TLS connection, then an additional layer of encryption protects the cyphertext in transport.

Comment: So is it a bad idea to have private key shipped with application so that every instance of app share the same PK, cause the only way I can think of to achieve this is to hardcode the key in my project, and that is something I em not sure I want to do. What is the best way to distribute key in client side encryption

Comment: the attacks your trying to guard against aren't overly clear, so instead i'll just give you some ideas to investigate

Comment: 1) the server gives the client the private key on first login, 2) every client generates a new key pair, 3) Diffie–Hellman key exchange, 4) Password-Based Key Derivation Function

Comment: as I said in the edit, I am trying to conform to new EU GDPR regulation. According to that regulation, in case of breach (on server side), data that is stolen should never relate to a real person. Two ways to accomplish this, anonymization and encryption. I have chosen client side encryption, cause if client encrypts data, it will never be possible to read in case of server breach, But if someone can easily steal my PK from my app, than after server breach it would be easy for him to connect data to real person. So how can I protect my PK the best?